# Decoding a QR code in an Android application?

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing

In Android, Using [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) we can scan a QR code through phone camera and decode it.

But, in my scenario, the QR code image is stored in the phone itself and I need to decode it.

Is there anyway to decode a QR image in this manner?

Comment: May I suggest a Google search? I'm pretty sure there are libraries out there.

Comment: there are libraries to scan a QR code through camera. but my requirement is bit different.

Comment: Veera, you can use ZXing code to do this from bitmaps and not the camera as per my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ZXing code for this.

Check out [DecodeHandler.java](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/DecodeHandler.java).

Comment: captureActivity capture QR code image from camera and after decoding it, it shows results according to type of data stored in QR code. e.g. if website URL is encoded in QR code, the result screen will have a button to open that URL and likevise.

I need to read image from SD card, decode it and handle the output in the same manner zxing does in case of decoding via captureActivity.

What do I need to do after getting output in "Result result"?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the Mobile Vision API for decoding a QR Code from Image.It is very accurate and can detect more than one Qr code over image.

You have to include the following library inorder to use Mobile Vision API :

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.6.1'

```
BarcodeDetector detector =
                new BarcodeDetector.Builder(context)
                        .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.DATA_MATRIX | Barcode.QR_CODE)
                        .build();
        if(!detector.isOperational()){
            Log.d("QR_READ","Could not set up the detector!");
        }
        Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
        SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detector.detect(frame);
            Log.d("QR_READ","-barcodeLength-"+barcodes.size());
            Barcode thisCode=null;
            if(barcodes.size()==0){
                Log.d("QR_VALUE","--NODATA");
            }
            else if(barcodes.size()==1){
                thisCode = barcodes.valueAt(0);
                Log.d("QR_VALUE","--"+thisCode.rawValue);
            }
            else{
                for(int iter=0;iter<barcodes.size();iter++) {
                    thisCode = barcodes.valueAt(iter);
                    Log.d("QR_VALUE","--"+thisCode.rawValue);
                }
            }
```