# how can i scan QR code using android camera?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to decode QR code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518858/how-to-decode-qr-code)

How can i use in an application the camera for scanning  QR or bar code and show me the results?

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

What do i have to put then to capture the image and get the information of the product?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you use ZXing library from google

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Android Barcode Scanner, uses that library and its performance is succesful

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the XZing library in addition to the standard Camera APIs.

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Answer (score 2):

I have previously used [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing) as a QR code capture library. It has worked very well for me. There is some good documentation on it too for Android.

Check out the getting started [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/GettingStarted).

Here is a good starter tutorial once you get going.
http://www.androidaz.com/development/zxing-qr-reader-direct-integration

Comment: I take a look of your example but is not working very well, just start the camera, but nothing else.