# Scanning QR code using Android's Mobile Vision API

Tags: java, android, qr-code, android-vision

I followed this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reading-qr-codes-using-the-mobile-vision-api--cms-24680) on how to build an Android app that can scan QR codes.

Here's the full code. I added the Google Play services using grade like so `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'`.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="bitinvent.io.qrscanner" >

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES" android:value="barcode"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/cameraView"
        android:layout_width="640px"
        android:layout_height="480px"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/infoTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cameraView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Nothing to read"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package bitinvent.io.qrscanner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SurfaceView cameraView;
    private TextView barcodeInfo;
    private CameraSource cameraSource;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.cameraView);
        barcodeInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoTextView);

        BarcodeDetector detector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this).setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE).build();
        cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, detector).setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480).build();

        cameraView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                try {
                    cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("CAMERA SOURCE", e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                cameraSource.stop();
            }
        });

        detector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {

            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
                final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
                if (barcodes.size() != 0) {
                    barcodeInfo.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            barcodeInfo.setText(barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I tested this on a HTC Desire 816 running Android 4.4.2. But it doesn't seem to work. The camera view is active but when pointed at a QR code, it doesn't detect anything. But no errors or crashes occur either.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, I know it's a pretty old question but I'm facing the same problem with android 4.4.2. On Android 6 it's working fine, but on this version the qr-code is never getting any result.. you know why?

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley No, I couldn't find a solution to this issue either. Sorry.

Comment: ok thanks you very much, I will tell you something if I find a workaround

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley Thank you. Do post an answer if you find anything.

Answer (score 7):

Finally I got it working in my side. I wanted to share the process and the code that I have right now to implement the QR code scanning in my application. I am not actually answering your question. However, I did not find any good source of help from StackOverflow regarding how can I implement QR code scanning using Google Vision API. I looked into the tutorial that you pointed in your question. However, the tutorial was not very helpful to me either. Hence I am putting down the classes and the steps to implement the QR code scanning in my application.

First of all, you will need some gradle dependencies. So in your `build.gradle` file, add the following dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.2.1'
}
```

Then, you need to have the following five classes in your project. I am adding the classes here. Please import the missing classes if necessary.

1. [CameraSource.java](https://gist.github.com/masudias/f8f37e8cf5e78c2c704cb4b6cbc5ddc8)
2. [CameraSourcePreview.java](https://gist.github.com/masudias/4810ccf3ae0c577e5da18d728afd1bb0)
3. [BarcodeCaptureActivity.java](https://gist.github.com/masudias/87cb9e525dc846d7b02fd8b5c5186ead)
4. [BarcodeGraphicTracker.java](https://gist.github.com/masudias/15063d72dc9dde69858055cff0527798)
5. [BarcodeTrackerFactory.java](https://gist.github.com/masudias/3f3b142b041b2dd2b33c6f114af57575)

Now `BarcodeCaptureActivity` has a layout which you need to put in your `layout` folder as well.

Here's the `barcode_capture.xml` layout that you need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Do not forget to replace with your package name where the class is located -->
    <com.example.yourpackage.camera.CameraSourcePreview
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You will need some strings and an activity entry in manifest for the `BarcodeCaptureActivity`. Here are the strings that you need to put in your `strings.xml`.

```
<!-- QR Code related strings -->
<string name="permission_camera_rationale">Access to the camera is needed for detection</string>
<string name="no_camera_permission">This application cannot run because it does not have the camera permission.  The application will now exit.</string>
<string name="low_storage_error">Face detector dependencies cannot be downloaded due to low device storage</string>
<string name="ok">OK</string>
```

And the `AndroidManifest.xml` should have a new entry for the `BarcodeCaptureActivity` like the following.

```
<activity
    android:name=".util.scanner.BarcodeCaptureActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" />
```

Now your setup is done and you are ready to open your camera for scanning a barcode or QR code. Just call the following `initiateScan` function where necessary.

```
public static final int RC_BARCODE_CAPTURE = 9001;

public void initiateScan() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, BarcodeCaptureActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_BARCODE_CAPTURE);
}
```

Please note that, you need to ask for camera permission to the user before you call `initiateScan` function. On granting the permission of the camera you will call the `initiateScan` function.

The `initiateScan` function will open the scanner and then after a successful scan, it will return to the calling `Activity` or `Fragment`. So you need to have a `onActivityResult` function in the calling `Activity` or `Fragment`.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS && requestCode == RC_BARCODE_CAPTURE) {
        if (data == null) return;
        Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra(BarcodeCaptureActivity.BarcodeObject);
        final String scanResult = barcode.displayValue;
        if (scanResult == null) return;

        doSomethingWithTheScanResult(scanResult);
    }
}
```

Do not forget to add the `CAMERA` permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file as well.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Hope that helps for easier integration of QR code scanner using Google Vision API. I have added a [github project](https://github.com/masudias/QRScanner) for a sample QR code scanner application. Please have a look.

Comment: What if I want it to scan QR code only in a square?

Comment: @c-an I think you have to implement the `SurfaceView` to get your camera opened in the squared box. There's a similar question that might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950904/how-to-open-camera-activity-in-selected-area

Comment: No, I mean full camera view but only scan when it's in a square box.

Answer (score 1):

Try move the following line

`<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES" android:value="barcode" />`

to your activity tag in yout manifest right after `<intent-filter/>`

so it would look like this

`<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES" android:value="barcode" />
</activity>`

Lemme know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Android development but I followed the tutorial using play services 8.1. Worked.

Code is very similar to yours. Only differences are that I have the meta tag under the application level and I removed .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE) since it limits it specifically to QR type codes.

Also used the app in landscape since portrait wasn't working for me. Even in landscape for QR codes I sometimes had to slowly move the QR code away from the camera until it was able to recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enabled internet connection in the device?
In order to download data via Google Play services; it requires internet connection over the device however you need not to provide any permission.